# Modify regex to disallow spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working with the following regex:

```
var currentVal = $(this).val();

//making sure it's only numbers, decimals, and commas
var isValid = /^[0-9,.]*$/.test(currentVal);
```

and I'm trying to modify it so that it disallows spaces as well.  I tried adding /s within the regex but it still allows it.  Newer to regex, gets confusing quick

Comment: So you are saying that isValid is returning true if the value has a space in it?

Comment: Your regex shouldn't allow whitespaces

Comment: The regex itself already disallows spaces: https://regex101.com/r/8q0hT5/1

Comment: Work well here https://jsfiddle.net/n57jwbuh/

Comment: @executable No, it should enable dots and commas.

Comment: @חייםפרידמן The fiddle example that executable linked *does* allow dots and commas.  What are you trying to say?

Comment: Voting to close because the described behavior is not replicated.

Comment: Do you need allow digits and comma and dot?

Answer (score 0):

The brackets `[]` in your regex form a character class. `^` means start of string and `$` means end of string with `*` applying the character class greedily multiple times. As it is written it should only allow characters specified in the class 0 through 9, comma, and period characters. If you tried adding in `\s` you would be also allowing for any whitespace characters in your character class, and thus cause your problem.

```js
console.log(/^[0-9,.]*$/.test("123 903"));
```

Comment: This is correct, but now the OP can't delete the incorrectly posted question because there's an answer!  It should just be closed now.

Comment: @Archer apologies. My aim was to educate. Since the OP clearly didn't understand the regular expression, I figured explaining it might be preferable to telling him "it already works" and sending him on his way. I can delete my answer if that helps.

Comment: No apology necessary - I was just trying to educate you too.  It's not the end of the world that this question isn't deleted.  That's just tidier :)